# How to find an index value for an element [with wild card] from an array?

Tags: python

a. Wanted to find the index of an element saved in the array. For which had this simple below code.

```
def find_index(self,needle,haystack):
    if needle == haystack: return []
    if isinstance(haystack,str) and len(haystack)<=1: return None
    try:
      for i,e in enumerate(haystack):
        r = self.find_index(needle,e)
        if r is not None: 
          r.insert(0,i)
          return r
    except TypeError:
      pass
    return None
```

But this search for exact match of the string inside an array and return the index. But I wanted index for partial match of the array element and return the index value.

For Eg:

a. `Array = ['fruit,apple,red', 'fruit,mango,yellow']`

b. Element to be searched is `'fruit,apple'`.

For the above program I need to pass the entire value i.e. `'fruit,apple,red'`.

c. But for my current scenario, I don't know the value of the 3rd variable [i.e. red] of the search element. So my input is just `'fruit,apple'`.

So, I wanted to search the array with partial element value and whichever array element matches the most, wanted to return the index value.

Any comments on what/how that needs to be done ?

Comment: Why not just `[i for i, x in enumerate(haystack) if needle in x]`?

Comment: Do you mean exact substring match, or do you have a specific wildcard/regex function in mind? What about "fruit,red"? What if one of those search terms happens to be a substring of a completely unrelated name in another term? Maybe a named tuple or a full class object would be better. You need to decide how to do that, then the rest is easy. But also you need to expect multiple matches.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Oh.. hmm.. will give a try..

Comment: @KennyOstrom: Well exact sub-string match. i.e. like the first two element and need the index of it.

Comment: wildcards are not going to work with the "in" operator at all. Substrings are going to bite you later but will get past this simple example. Split will help here. I caution against taking shortcuts just because the two search terms you want in this case happen to be adjacent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `in` operator to check if a substring matches a string. For example:

```
>>> 'oba' in 'foobar'
True
```

We can exploit this in list comprehension, for example:

```
def find_index(needle,haystack):
    return [i for i, x in enumerate(haystack) if needle in x]
```

For example:

```
>>> find_index('fruit', ['fruit,apple,red', 'fruit,mango,yellow'])
[0, 1]
>>> find_index('fruit,apple', ['fruit,apple,red', 'fruit,mango,yellow'])
[0]
```